# Correctly implementing asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to use the [ensembl genome browser](https://uswest.ensembl.org/index.html) api to get some genomic information. The challenge is that each network request can take a few seconds, so I have been trying to use `asyncio` to wait for these network requests while simultaneously working with the data I have.

Here is a sample input DataFrame that I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gene Name': {0: 'A1CF', 1: 'A1CF', 2: 'A1CF'},
 'Sample Name': {0: 'ATL045', 1: 'QC2-20-T2', 2: 'GHE0624'},
 'CDS Mutation': {0: 'c.234A>C', 1: 'c.492C>T', 2: 'c.490G>A'},
 'AA Mutation': {0: 'p.K78N', 1: 'p.V164V', 2: 'p.V164I'}})
```

The goal is to use the `Gene Name` and `CDS Mutation` info from the above `df` to get some other genomic info.

This first method is designed to call the `ensembl_calls` method which will make a network request and return some parsed output. Ideally that parsed output gets combined into something like a master pandas dataframe.

```
async def concurrent_location_info(df):
    import pandas as pd
    import asyncio

    full_df = pd.DataFrame()

    # iterate through DataFrame
    dfs = [asyncio.ensure_future(ensembl_calls(row)) for index, row in df.iterrows()]

    print(dfs)
```

In this method I am trying to make my network requests and parse the information i get back.

```
# this makes the network ensembl call asynchronously
async def ensembl_calls(row):
    new_df = {}

    try: # sometimes ensembl can't find what i'm looking for
        # this can take a while
        await info = Ensembl(row['Gene Name'], row['CDS Mutation']).info().split(',')

        # parse the output
        new_df['Gene'] = row['Gene Name']
        new_df['Chrom'] = info[0]
        new_df['Start'] = info[1]
        new_df['End'] = info[2]
        new_df['WT'] = info[3]
        new_df['Var'] = info[4]
        new_df['Sift_Index'] = info[5]
    except:
        pass

    return new_df # ideally somehow gets added to a master pd dataframe
```

Am I on the right track here? Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @user2357112 the code doesn't work as is because i haven't correctly implemented asyncio. I'm looking for help in correcting this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import asyncio


async def concurrent_location_info(df):
    # iterate through DataFrame
    tasks = [ensembl_calls(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
    df = pd.concat(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    print(df)
```

and modify the second function like this

```
info = await Ensembl(...)
```

This assumes that Ensembl has an async **init** method, which is an uncommon pattern.